# how to change language in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've saved a product name in my DB with two language (En & Fr)

how can i load them differently by just changing the url

for example

```
localhost/mysite/en/products/
```

loads the "en_name" out of my table

and

```
localhost/mysite/fr/products/
```

loads the "fr_name" for me?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i've tried doing it by language library but i don't know how to tell it to loads the names from my db :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest method may be to pass the uri segment to the where clause of the query.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=select#selecting-data

Something like:

```
$lang = $this-uri->segment(3);
$this->db->where('language', $lang);
$this->db->get('table');
```

Answer (score 1):

The language library is used if you want to store the text in different languages in a file (it will be included in the page) and not in a database. So if the language text is stored in the database, you want to check the method responsible for checking the url segment to check if the url contains the `en` or the `fr` and load the corresponding language.

So the method to use is:

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

More info on how to use it:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

and your condition should be something like:
**Edit**

```
if($this->uri->segment(1) == "fr"){
   $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'fr');
}else{
   $this->session->set_userdata('lang', 'en');
}
```

Now you can easily check for the language selected from the `model` (db files) by checking the value of the `lang` Session

Comment: my problem isn't with segment or like that , my problem is when i called the "en" or "fr" , how tell it to load the "en_name" or "fr_name" fields of my db for my all products

Comment: @hamidreza Check my updated answer, I used session to specify the language used, and of course it will be accessible by all pages

Comment: @hamidreza why did you remove the "Solved" ?

Answer (score 0):

i finally did it with this CI extension [i18n](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n) and here is my code:

```
$lang = $this->uri->segment(1);
echo $prodct[$lang."_name"];
```

so now if i enter my url like this

```
localhost/mysite/en/products/
```

it will get those fields from DB which is like "en_name" ,
same goes for "fr" too.